# Boxing after unary operation on a Character

Tags: java, type-conversion, character, boxing, unboxing

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Character x = ' ';
    while (x++ < 50) {
        int p = x;
    }
    System.out.println(x instanceof Character);
  }
```

Because it's a unary operation ++. x is unboxed into char and then widened into int before operation is performed.
When I exit the loop, I get 'true'.
I fail to understand how can int be boxed into Character back; java can allow boxing of int into Integer or boxing and widening int into Number, Object etc.

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in the Java Language Specification [§15.14.2 Postfix Increment Operator ++](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.14.2)

(Emphasis by me)

> At run time, if evaluation of the operand expression completes
>   abruptly, then the postfix increment expression completes abruptly for
>   the same reason and no incrementation occurs. Otherwise, the value 1
>   is added to the value of the variable and the sum is stored back into
>   the variable. Before the addition, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2)
>   is performed on the value 1 and the value of the variable. **If
>   necessary, the sum is narrowed by a narrowing primitive conversion
>   (§5.1.3) and/or subjected to boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to the type of
>   the variable before it is stored.** The value of the postfix increment
>   expression is the value of the variable before the new value is
>   stored.